# PowerApps Customer Support Portal will not show field

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-portal

I'm trying to do something very simple in displaying on a customer support portal the 'owner' of the support case.  However, no matter what I do I can't get this field to show on the particular 'Edit Case' web page.

I have added the field 'Owner' to the form (changed label to 'Assigned To').
[Form Creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eeg3s.png)

I have then published this and synced it with the web page, but as you can see the field does not appear in the web page:

[web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL2ef.png)

I have tried everything I can think of but this field will not appear on the form, on either the actual portal or the web form creation page. I have tried:

- Hiding/showing the field.
- Creating a new form based on the current
  one
- Creating a brand new form with the owner field on.
- Clearing the portal cache

The strange thing is I have a list page showing all the cases and the owner displays perfectly here.

[list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du5Ii.png)

I'm really stuck to why this field will not display at all on this form.
Pete

**EDIT:**

As I move the field up and down the form I can see a blank row moving up and down the form field, it's like it can't display the field at all.

[blank area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odrMt.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First thing First, Is your Form "case" (Entity Case-->incident) the correct form on PowerPortals?

In most cases (out of the box) it is Case Portals Forms. Please check this.

Second thing, clear your portals cache.
Login in to Portals as Admin and then use below url, clear cache, It shall help.

https://[yourURL].powerappsportals.com/_services/about

let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your response, yes this is a form against the 'Case (incident)' entity.  I've also cleared the cache on the portal many many times.  The entity doesn't even show on the PowerApps portal edit page, before it is even published to the portal itself.

Comment: I can actually see a blank row in the form that moves around as I move the form field up and down the order.  It's like it's there, but refuses to show any data.

Comment: please add screenshot of Portal management Form 'Case (incident)' and it's metadata. Also please add screenshot if there is any custom js against it, you can see that in portal management app. Also please try publishing portal itself and check live (rather on portal edit page)